# как вывести в цикле в шаблон PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

как вывести в шаблон, записи в цикле, на данный момент в шаблон выводится только одна строка, хотя цикл выводит 4 строки

```
 $sql="SELECT mu.fullname, mp.name as namep, mp.price as pricep FROM   modx_shopkeeper3_orders  mo
    left JOIN  modx_shopkeeper3_purchases mp on mp.order_id=mo.id
    left join modx_user_attributes mu on mu.id=mo.userid
    where mo.id=36";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
          $document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('chek.docx'); //шаблон
    $document->setValue('user', 'Иванов'); //
    while ($parent = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $document->setValue('blyudo', $parent['namep'].'.....'.$parent['pricep']); //фамилияотчество

    }
    $document->setValue('city', 'Минск'); //фамилияотчество
    $document->save('Template_full.docx'); //имя заполненного шаблона для сохранения 

     }
     }
```

шаблон

```
Обед ${fio}
${name} ${price}


Приятного аппетита!!!
${adress}
```

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Чем вам `while ($parent = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` не цикл? Приведите пример  входных и выходных данных(которые хочеться).

Comment: цикл то у меня и выводит

суши  200р
десерт  300р
салат  450р

но в шаблон документа записывается только  салат 450р, а предыдущие не записываются

Comment: Ну так логично. Вы в одну переменную пишете разные значения. А потом "записываете" последнее значение... Тут или шаблон с циклом делать или в цикле делать переменную в которой есть все.

Comment: разобрался
while ($parent = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $blyudo .= $parent['namep'].".....".$parent['pricep']."\n";
}
 
$document->setValue('blyudo', $blyudo);

Comment: а как распечатать этот файл потом, в документации не нашел